# How to make an underground connection to 4 inch clay drain pipe

Tags: drain, pipe

I need to connect to an existing 4" clay drain pipe opening that will be underground, and I don't want dirt/sand to enter the joint.  Are there connector pieces that form a tight joint?  For extra protection, would it make sense to wrap the joint in landscaping fabric held by zipties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use something like this:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-x-4-in-PVC-DWV-Mechanical-Flexible-Coupling-P1056-44/100372298

The worm drive and rubber make a good bond.  This is used in vertical and horizontal sewage applications both residentally and commercially so I wouldn't bother with landscape fabric and zip ties.  Chances are if you are joining to tile the tile will be replaced at some later stage down the road.

Comment: Thanks.  The following similar item allows for the larger OD of the clay pipe:    https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-Clay-x-4-in-DWV-Flexible-PVC-Coupling-P1002-44/100372311